# Travel on US B1/B2 visa thru Amsterdam

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel, mexico-city

I have a US Business/Tourist Visa on my Indian Passport and want to travel to Mexico City for business. Can I travel via Amsterdam? I want to avoid transiting US as it is increasing my travel cost.

Comment: Maybe you could spell out explicitly what sort of information you are after: Are you concerned about visa requirements? Asking about flight schedules?

Comment: I don't understand why you think your US visa is relevant to travel via Amsterdam. Where are you traveling from?

Comment: Hello Friends, I know , i can travel to Mexico city with US valid visa, transiting US airports. But i want to avoid US as it will increase my travel cost. So, is it ok having US visa but not transiting thru USA and going directly to Mexico using Europe Transit.I will be travelling from Newdelhi.India.

Answer (score 3):

@neubert covered the flight schedule. If your question is whether you need an airport transit visa, you do not (the tags suggest it's at least part of the question).

Even if Indian citizens would generally need one (and that's not the case in Amsterdam, even though it is for France or Germany), holding a valid US visa would exempt you from this requirement *even if you are not currently travelling to the US.*

See also [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. [Aeromexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerom%C3%A9xico) and [KLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=KLM&redirect=no) both have direct flights to Mexico City from Amsterdam. eg. [Flight AM6501](https://www.google.com/search?q=AM6501) and [Flight KL685](https://www.google.com/search?q=KL685)